Critique my weightlifting workout plan
I'm 5'10 24yo 165lbs looking to get to around 200lbs, eating 3900 cal a day. Only 8 months in so I'm getting good response from my body but I want to fine tune my workout as much as I can. Any critique could be helpful.
My weaker muscle groups I hit 3 times a week, all others 2 times. The curl variations are repeated because I can't curl in a supinated position right now.
Cardio: only for warming up. A good 10 minute run at 6.5-7 on the treadmill.
Muscle Groups

Monday - chest shoulders bicep
Tuesday - back tricep traps
Wednesday - legs bicep
Thursday - chest tricep back
Friday - shoulders bicep traps
Saturday - legs tricep

Workout
Monday
Incline dumbbell Bench      4x6(65)
Dumbbell Fly                3x10(32.5)
EZ Bar Curl                 4 failure sets(15)
Decline Press               3x10(55)
Lat Raise                   4 failure sets(17.5)
Hammer Curl                 4x10(37.5) 
Dumbbell Rear Delt Fly      rep match(22.5)
Single Arm Overhead Press   3x10(100)

Tuesday
Chest supported row         3x10(130)
Dumbbell Row                3x8(47.5) 
Tricep Pulldown             4x8(70)
DB French Press             4x8(25)
DB Shrug                    4 failure sets(60)
Single arm Seated Row       3x8(70)
High Row Machine            4x10(65)

Wednesday
Lying Leg Curl              3x9(80)
Stiff Leg Deadlift          3x8(195)
Bulg Split Squat            3x10(40)
Leg Curl                    4x10(130)
Leg Press                   3x10(145)
Leg Extension               4x12(110)
EZ Bar Curl                 4x8(25)
Hammer curl

Thursday
Incline Bench               3x10(50) 
Decline Press Machine       3x10(55) 
Pec Deck                    3x12(130)
T Row                       3x10(75)
SA Lat Pulldown Machine     3x8(75)
Seated Row                  3x8(60)
Tricep Pulldown             4x8(70)
Skull Crusher               3x8(50)

Friday
Military Press              4x8(80)
Lat Raise                   4x11(20)
Rear Delt Fly               3 failure sets(140)
Hammer Curl                 4x10(37.5)
EZ Curl                     4x8(25)
Shrug                       4 failure sets(62)

Saturday
Barbell Squat               3x15(155) 
Leg Press                   3x10(150) 
BSS                         3x10(40) 
Leg Curl                    4 match rep sets(130)
Leg Extension               4 match rep sets(110) 
Hack Squat                  3x10(130)
Tricep Pulldown             4x8(70)
Skull Crusher               4x8(50)


What have been your results over the last 8 months?

If you want to gain 35 pounds of mostly muscle your list of exercises is not the important part. What's important is that you eat a lot, prioritize the project, and lift heavy.
The fact that you're trying to hit a calorie target with 100-calorie precision (3900 rather than 4000, really?) makes me think you're overthinking this. The fact that you're doing five or six leg exercises makes me think you're overthinking this.
What I expect to hear from someone who is serious and focused on what's important is "I'm well prepared for all my meals, so I'm never hungry. So far I've gained X pounds of body weight and my X, Y, Z lifts have gone up by Q, R, S pounds. At least one set per exercise is at an extremely high intensity except for deload weeks."

I don't want to gain too much fat compared to muscle. I track all my food since I started in May and 4000+ makes me gain weight too quickly at the weight Im at now so I went back to 3800-3900 cals daily. Im "lean bulking" so I can use my naturally slim build to my advantage and not have to cut after bulking. My nutrition is on point since it's the most important part of building muscle for me at least. I was 125 in May when I started so gained about 40lbs while remaining 10-12% body fat. I guess I was more asking about the exercises and if I was missing anything important.

The rep range of my plan is if it's 8 reps then the 8th rep is 1-2 from failure in terms of how hard I'm working. The first 2-3 months of this whole thing I got myself a personal trainer so he could show me how to workout hard and with proper form but since I took it on my own its been a while since I checked in with anybody about it so Im here now. Once I can get to 10-12 clean reps at any specific weight then I move it up 2.5lb or 5lb depending on if its a dumbbell or plate weight. Just to give you an idea of how Im working this.

also on leg days I do lying leg curls as a warmup for my legs not working sets

@PaulManning your progress so far is impressive! I'm not sure the same tactics will get you to 200lbs so you'll have to see. Your progression strategy with reps sounds good.
